# Find k closest from billions of coordinates in 3D space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bigdata

Given the x,y,z coordinates of a billion stars (basically the entire array can’t fit in the RAM) calculate the k closest.(Amazon interview question)

What are the possible solutions of this problem.

Comment: Do `k` coordinates fit into RAM? Also, closest to what, a fixed point or to each other?

Comment: The question is asking about an out-of-memory minheap data structure.  Of course, a few billion star fits into memory (particularly at Amazon), these days.

Comment: It is not entirely clear (which may well be the interviewer's intention) whether there is only one point in space for which these `k closest` are sought, queries of this type are to be supported or those k neighbours are to be found for each star (giving rise to disparate approaches more likely than not).

Comment: As i understood it is the case of each other, where a closest has the minimum distance from each other having k starts, so finally making the most dense collection of (k) stars. And only possibility that k coordinates can fit into RAM (Assumed).

Comment: Perhaps *k* closest pairs?

Comment: k stars pairs, having minimum total distance.

Comment: If there is room to keep `k` pairs in memory, then you can use a standard heap-based selection algorithm. Otherwise you're probably better off with a map/reduce approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [R-tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)s.